# REGEX in PIGlatin

Tags: regex, apache-pig

How can we use **REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL** command in PIG to extract all occurrences of data within square brackets ?

Apparently `'\[(.*?)\]'` doesn't work.

Comment: Whaaat ?
That is for ?

Comment: You may include an example, as the REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL function relies on Java class Pattern

Comment: Also, remember that each tuple has as many fields as the number of matches found by the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\[(.*?)\\]` should do it.

You need to escape `[]`.

Comment: Thanks.
I did figure that out. It didn't work because I was using reserved word as a name for a relation.